# How to get Value field from HTML in AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I have a "remember me" checkbox that I toggle the value in the value field from 0 -> 1. I want to get the value and send it to my backend. This is my current

```
<input value="1" id="remember-me-checkbox" onchange="rememberMeCheckBox(this)" type="checkbox" checked> Remember Me
```

And this is my script function:

```
        $.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url:'/signin/check/',
         data:{
             email:$('#email').val(),
             password:$('#password').val(),
             rememberMeCheckBox:$('#remember-me-checkbox').val(),
             csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
         },
```

getting the ".val()" isnt returning what I want. Any ideas?

Comment: By using serialize function. please follow https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$('#remember-me-checkbox').is(':checked')` it will return `boolean` type for you, then you can convert it to `int` if you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

Just try like this.

```
$count = $('#remember-me-checkbox:checked').length;
console.log($count);
```